# Trying to align text with different lengths in css

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align text with different lengths in two different grid boxes, Here's an Image of my problem [image]

As you can see the a tags at the bottom don't line up as the text for the description is longer in the grid box on the left. Here's an example of my code:

```css
.project-list{
    margin: 2em;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(455px, 1fr));
    gap: 5px; 

    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.project-list div{
    padding-left: 2em;
    padding-right: 2em;
    border: 5px solid #1e1e1e;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section class="project-list">
            <div id="Aura Server Manager">     
                <br>     
                <img src="https://contenthub-static.grammarly.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/how-to-ask-for-help.jpg" width="auto" height="200px"/>
                <h2>AURA SERVER MANAGER</h2>
                <b><p>Status: In Development</p></b>
                <p>Aura server manager is a discord bot I'm currently developing using discord.py rewrite, The bot has many features that allow you to control a server and view information on a range of things such as user and server info.</p>
                <a href="https://github.com/JacobA2000/Discord-Server-Moderation-Bot" target="_blank">View on GitHub</a>
            </div>
            
            <div id="Discord Bot Tutorial Series">
                <br>          
                <img src="https://contenthub-static.grammarly.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/how-to-ask-for-help.jpg" width="auto" height="200px"/>
                <h2>Discord Bot Tutorial Series</h2>
                <b><p>Status: In Development</p></b>
                <p>The Discord Bot Tutorial Series is a Youtube playlist I'm producing to try and teach people how to make discord bots in Python.</p>
                <a href="https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLYw1kd-gvJjNxXLe2UdaH2k5Iyl_pvkUH" target="_blank">View on YouTube</a>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Comment: Have you tried setting a static height on the description element?

Comment: Thank you, can't believe I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
.project-list div a{
   align-items: flex-end
}
```

to your CSS.

```css
.project-list{
    margin: 2em;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(455px, 1fr));
    gap: 5px; 

    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.project-list div{
    padding-left: 2em;
    padding-right: 2em;
    border: 5px solid #1e1e1e;
    height: 100%;
}

.project-list div a{
    align-items: flex-end
}
```

```html
<section class="project-list">
            <div id="Aura Server Manager">     
                <br>     
                <img src="https://contenthub-static.grammarly.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/how-to-ask-for-help.jpg" width="auto" height="200px"/>
                <h2>AURA SERVER MANAGER</h2>
                <b><p>Status: In Development</p></b>
                <p>Aura server manager is a discord bot I'm currently developing using discord.py rewrite, The bot has many features that allow you to control a server and view information on a range of things such as user and server info.</p>
                <a href="https://github.com/JacobA2000/Discord-Server-Moderation-Bot" target="_blank">View on GitHub</a>
            </div>
            
            <div id="Discord Bot Tutorial Series">
                <br>          
                <img src="https://contenthub-static.grammarly.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/how-to-ask-for-help.jpg" width="auto" height="200px"/>
                <h2>Discord Bot Tutorial Series</h2>
                <b><p>Status: In Development</p></b>
                <p>The Discord Bot Tutorial Series is a Youtube playlist I'm producing to try and teach people how to make discord bots in Python.</p>
                <a href="https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLYw1kd-gvJjNxXLe2UdaH2k5Iyl_pvkUH" target="_blank">View on YouTube</a>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Comment: The problem with this is that the container is not a flex element....

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this effect would be to apply `position: absolute` to the footer link:

```
a {
  position: absolute;
}
```

Once you apply `position: absolute` *and* the co-ordinates (in this case `bottom: 6px` and `left: 0`) you'll need to explicitly declare the `width` and it's also better to explicitly declare `display: block`:

```
a {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 6px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

For the `absolute` positioning co-ordinates to be *co-ordinates relating to* the parent `<div>`, it's necessary to give that `<div>` positioning too - in this case, `position: relative` is sufficient.

```
div {
  position: relative;
}
```

Finally, you'll want to make sure there is a reasonable space underneath the paragraph for the absolutely-positioned link to occupy:

```
p {
  margin-bottom: 24px;
}
```

**Working Example:**

```css
.project-list{
    margin: 2em;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(455px, 1fr));
    gap: 5px; 

    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.project-list div{
    padding-left: 2em;
    padding-right: 2em;
    border: 5px solid #1e1e1e;
    height: 100%;
}

div {
  position: relative;
}

p {
  margin-bottom: 24px;
}

a {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 6px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section class="project-list">
            <div id="Aura Server Manager">     
                <br>     
                <img src="https://contenthub-static.grammarly.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/how-to-ask-for-help.jpg" width="auto" height="200px"/>
                <h2>AURA SERVER MANAGER</h2>
                <b><p>Status: In Development</p></b>
                <p>Aura server manager is a discord bot I'm currently developing using discord.py rewrite, The bot has many features that allow you to control a server and view information on a range of things such as user and server info.</p>
                <a href="https://github.com/JacobA2000/Discord-Server-Moderation-Bot" target="_blank">View on GitHub</a>
            </div>
            
            <div id="Discord Bot Tutorial Series">
                <br>          
                <img src="https://contenthub-static.grammarly.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/how-to-ask-for-help.jpg" width="auto" height="200px"/>
                <h2>Discord Bot Tutorial Series</h2>
                <b><p>Status: In Development</p></b>
                <p>The Discord Bot Tutorial Series is a Youtube playlist I'm producing to try and teach people how to make discord bots in Python.</p>
                <a href="https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLYw1kd-gvJjNxXLe2UdaH2k5Iyl_pvkUH" target="_blank">View on YouTube</a>
            </div>
        </section>
```